# Парсим string to float без экспоненты в C#

Tags: c#, .net, float, числа, конвертация

Ситуация простейшая, но именно на ней я застрял.
Есть следующий метод, конвертирующий строку в `float?`

```
public static float? ToSingleNullable(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return null;
    else
    {
        float number = 0;
        if (float.TryParse(value, out number))
            return number;
        return null;
    }
}
```

В ситуации, когда на входе приходит что-то больше 19 999 999, то `float.TryParse` вместо, скажем, 20 000 012 выводит 2e+6 или где-то там. При обратной конвертации в лучшем случае получаю 20 000 010. Причём предсказать, что получится - 20 000 000 или 20 000 010 не могу.

В общем, как сделать так, чтобы вот текущий метод возвращал число с плавающей точкой именно в десятичной записи?

В сети куча примеров для `.ToString()`, а вот с обратной конвертацией пусто. Сменить на `decimal` не выйдет - метод должен вернуть именно `float`.

Строку вводит пользователь в человеческом виде. То есть грубо говоря получается такое:

```
string str = "20100999";
float number = ToSingleNullable(str);
Console.WriteLine(number);//условно 2е+6
```

Comment: Так вам надо от экспоненты избавиться при конвертации в строку может?

Comment: @tym32167 строка приходит из TextBox'a или таблицы уже в адекватном виде. Обновил вопрос

Comment: [Standard numeric format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), [Custom numeric format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, это всё для .ToString() если я правильно вижу, а мне нужно как раз наоборот

Comment: Это float и у него есть погрешности. Используйте либо double, либо decimal

Comment: в общем, вам надо понять, что float- тип с [опредленной точностью](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types), потому результат парсинга может отличаться от строки.

Comment: Нет, не наоборот. Вам нужно указывать формат при _выводе_.

Comment: Во-первых, используйте `double`, во-вторых в вашем коде конвертация в обе стороны, а вы обращаете внимание только на одну.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, упростим ваш метод до следующего:

```
public static float? ToSingleNullable(string value)
{
    if (float.TryParse(value, out float number))
        return number;
    return null;
}
```

Теперь немного теории.

Вещественные числа имеют некоторую точность. Она не может быть бесконечной, потому что тогда потребуется бесконечное количество памяти для хранения одного числа. Соответственно, неизбежно часть данных теряется.

```
float f = 20100999;
Console.WriteLine(f); // 2,0101E+07
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("F0")); // 20101000
```

Из этого примера следует, что значение `20100999` *невозможно* точно представить в виде вещественного числа одинарной точности.

Следовательно, если вы хотите получить *представление* числа в определённом виде, то нужно задать желаемый формат: [Standard numeric format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), [Custom numeric format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

Я использовал формат `F` с указанием спецификатора точности: 0 десятичных знаков.

```
string str = "20100999";
float? number = ToSingleNullable(str);
Console.WriteLine(number.Value.ToString("F0")); // 20101000
```

---

Дополню. У числа в двоичном виде *нет* никакого формата. Это просто набор нолей и единиц.

```
float f = 20100999;
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);

foreach (byte b in bytes)
    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(b, 2) + " ");
Console.WriteLine();
```

Результат:

```
11000100 1011011 10011001 1001011
```

Это и есть искомое число в памяти компьютера. А экспоненциальная форма она только для нас, для людей. Мы можем эти биты вывести в разных удобных для нас представлениях.